# Zip multiple files into individual .gz files (windows)

Tags: windows, gzip, 7zip

Hoping somebody might be able to help me find a quicker way to do this:

I have 640 files that each need to be individually zipped into their own .gz file.

7-zip only allows zipping of 1 file to .gz at a time. Is there a way I can do all 640 in one go, while retaining them as individual files? (running windows)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use tar + 7zip. Why you use the gz format?

Comment: Unfortunately tar + 7zip not an option. Needs to exclusively be the .gz format. Why gz: because it's how our data pipeline was designed to ingest data. We're updating it in a few months. But gotta make do for now.

Comment: do you need a script that cycles through all the files and generates the respective gz?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late, but to help myself and others who come across this in the future, one can use a shell script to execute the 7Zip command line on each file.

The key lines below are the `foreach` loop and the PowerShell call operator for the `7z.exe` executable.

- Command `a` for adding a file to an archive.
- `-tgzip` to specify Gzip format.
- `"$newFileName.gz"` as the archive name.
- `$newFileName` as the name of the file to be zipped.

**Warning!** *In my use case, I was renaming files with new dates in the filenames, you might want to change the logic...*

PowerShell Example:

```sh
$files=[System.IO.FileInfo[]](Get-ChildItem ./*.txt);

$now=[System.DateTime]::Now.Date;
$span=[System.TimeSpan]::FromDays($files.Length);
$startDate=$now - $span;
$files=Sort-Object -InputObject $files -Property Name;

$index=0;
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $newDateText = ($startDate + [TimeSpan]::FromDays($index)).ToString('yyyyMMdd');
    $newFileName = "myPrefix.$newDateText.txt";
    Write-Host "$($file.Name) => " -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline;
    Write-Host "$newFileName.gz" -ForegroundColor Green;
    #Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $newFileName;
    & "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tgzip "$newFileName.gz" $newFileName
    $index += 1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not forced to use 7-zip, there are command-line alternatives.
One is to download the `gzip.exe` binary from https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm and run that on the command line:

```
c:\my_data> gzip.exe -v *.data
```

I do not guarantee that this binary is safe, but I have no particular reason to believe it is not. Your IT department may not approve of downloading and executing binaries.

Or, if you happen to have either Git for Windows, MinGW compiler or MSYS2 compiler environment installed, those environments include `gzip`. Open the environment terminal (f.ex. Git Bash):

```
~ > cd /c/my_data
/C/my_data > gzip -v *.data
```

Answer (score 0):

gzip multipe xml files separately by preserving the names (just delete *.xml* if you wanna include just everything):

via CMD

```
for %i in (*.xml) do 7z a -tgzip "%i.gz" "%i"
```

Note: `"%~ni.gz"` if you don't want to keep the extension in the output file name.

via POWERSHELL

```
Get-ChildItem *.xml | ForEach-Object { & 7z a -tgzip "$($_.BaseName).xml.gz" "$($_.FullName)" }
```

**Remember to replace *7z* with *"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"* (or whatever the path to 7z.exe is) if you get an error.**